# Read request URL in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-1

I am not a flash developer, but I am stuck with a flash developer, stuck with a third party program in ActionScript1.

I asked him to get the request URL of the page which embeds the flash object (like reading the address bar in the browser). and then get Query string variables and send it back to an application.

How to read those variables?  Remember it is action script1.

Thanks

Comment: I think _root._url will give you the whole URL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I used javascript like this, thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function writeFlash()
        {
            var id = '';

            var queryString = new String();
            queryString = window.location.search;

            if (queryString != null)
            {
                var parts = new Array();
                parts = queryString.split("&");

                parts = parts[0].split("=");
                id = parts[1];

            }



            var ieObj = '<div id="flashContent">'
            + '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1200" height="800" id="BookFlipping" align="middle">'
            + '<param name="movie" value="BookFlipping.swf" />'
            + '<param name="quality" value="high" />'
            + '<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />'
            + '<param name="play" value="true" />'
            + '<param name="loop" value="true" />'
            + '<param name="wmode" value="window" />'
            + '<param name="scale" value="showall" />'
            + '<param name="menu" value="true" />'
            + '<param name="devicefont" value="false" />'
            + '<param name="salign" value="" />'
            + '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />'

            + '<PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="ID='
            + id
            + '"/>'

            + '<!--[if !IE]>-->'
            + '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="BookFlipping.swf" width="1200" height="800">'
            + '<param name="movie" value="BookFlipping.swf" />'
            + '<param name="quality" value="high" />'
            + '<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />'
            + '<param name="play" value="true" />'
            + '<param name="loop" value="true" />'
            + '<param name="wmode" value="window" />'
            + '<param name="scale" value="showall" />'
            + '<param name="menu" value="true" />'
            + '<param name="devicefont" value="false" />'
            + '<param name="salign" value="" />'
            + '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />'

            + '<PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="ID='
            + id
            + '"/>';

            + '<!--<![endif]-->'
            + '<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">'
            + '<img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />'
            + '</a>'
            + '<!--[if !IE]>-->'
            + '</object>'
            + '<!--<![endif]-->'
            + '</object>';

            //alert(ieObj);
            document.write(ieObj);


        }
    </script>


<body>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
    writeFlash();
    -->
    </script> 


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over how the movie is embedded? If so just add that information to the flash vars that you embed the movie with and reference it that way.